# Remove specific dataset and not pop last one added

Tags: javascript, charts

I am trying to remove/hide/pop a certain dataset from my chart when I have more than 2. pop(ing) it only removes the last dataset push(ed). Please see below:

```
$('#radar2015').on('change', function () {
        var newDataset2 = {
            label: '2016',
            data: [2019, 552, 750, 1280, 1190, 2345, 2123, 534, 1234],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 183, 253, .25)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(0, 183, 253)',
            borderWidth: 2
        };
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            radarChart.data.datasets.push(newDataset2);
        }
        else {
            radarChart.data.datasets.pop();
        }
        radarChart.update();
    });
    $('#radar2016').on('change', function () {
        var newDataset3 = {
            label: '2017',
            data: [3235, 1125, 2650, 1380, 990, 2345, 123, 1234, 1234],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 40, 180, .25)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(220, 40, 180)',
            borderWidth: 2
        };
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            radarChart.data.datasets.push(newDataset3);
        }
        else {
            radarChart.data.datasets.pop();
        }
        radarChart.update();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for removing specific values from array

```
radarChart.data.datasets.filter((item) => {
 // condition for removing dataset
});
```

> Note: filter() returns a new Array everytime

Example from MDN:

```
var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Got it to work

`code`
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                radarChart.data.datasets.push(newDataset2);
            }
            else {
                radarChart.data.datasets = radarChart.data.datasets.filter(d => d.label !== "2018");
            }
            radarChart.update();
        });